# Variable is set to null when JSF Ajax call is made

Tags: ajax, jsf-2.2

I have a `@ViewScoped` wordController CDI bean. It has a method `addWord()` that adds variable `currentWord` to a `List`. It works fine with no AJAX, but as soon as I include the `f:ajax`, the variable `currentWord` is always null in the `addWord()` method. There is something I am missing on the way ajax works with JSF. What is going wrong here?

```
<h:form id="saveForm" styleClass="form">
    <h:inputText value="#{wordController.currentWord}" id="words" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{wordController.addWord()}" type="submit" value="+">
        <f:ajax render="wordlist" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGroup id="wordlist">
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f:ajax` defaults to `execute="@this"` (which in this case equals to the `commandButton`), so the inputText is not executed (≈ submitted). Thats why it is null in the action. Just add

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="wordlist" />
```

to execute the whole form, or

```
<f:ajax execute="@this words" render="wordlist" />
```

to only execute the inputText and the button - in case there are more inputcomponents you don't want submitted.

In the latter case you need `@this` because without it only `words` would execute, and therefore not the `commandButton`, and therefore not the action.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/25349610#25349610)'s more reading.